# Forward slashes in stdClass object parsing JSON?

Tags: php, json, stdclass

I'm trying to access data within a JSON object I create using json_decode (based on a result from a URL). The response is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000016f4c9cd] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => /api/status/ok
            [result] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [

..
```

How do I access the parameter "code"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this slightly more quirky syntax:

```
print $stdclass->{'/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000016f4c9cd'}->code;
```

It's intended specifically for non-ascii attribute names. (There's also the variant with double quotes, which is useful for variable `->{"attr_$index"}` attribute names.)

---

The other option would be to have [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) create an associative array instead, by passing TRUE as second parameter.

Comment: As a followup, can I access [/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000016f4c9cd] by any method (like iterating through, get the name of the stdClass).

Comment: Yes that's possible. Because when you `foreach` over the attributes, you are accessing the object with `$obj->$varname`. And in that case `$varname` can be anything (excluding the \0 character). And foreaching over the object also gives you the real attribute names.